# Is it possible to create Google Sheets data validation rules using Python and gdata.spreadsheet?

Tags: python, gdata

I am able to get the cell contents, but the validation rules don't seem to be accessible. I've got working code based on this:

https://github.com/google/gdata-python-client

Apps script seems like it can do it:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets

I prefer to do this in Python if possible.

Ideas?

Thanks,

-dj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Google Sheets API v4, this can be done.  Here's a brief intro to the new version:

http://wescpy.blogspot.com/2016/06/using-new-google-sheets-api.html

Here are some details about how to programmatically create validations:

https://developers.google.com/sheets/samples/data#apply_data_validation_to_a_range

I have verified it works in Python using `google-api-python-client 1.5.1`